# PHP + curl, HTTP POST to Open cart, add to cart section?

Tags: api, session, opencart, php-curl

Can anyone show me how to do a PHP curl with an HTTP POST to open cart using API?

I want to send data like this:

```
product_id = 700, quantity = 1
```

To `www.example.com`

I expect the curl to return a response like `{"success":"Success: You have modified your shopping cart!"}` Are there any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do it the way as below:**

```
<?php
$output = apirequest();
function apirequest()
{
    $params['product_id'] = 700;
    $params['quantity'] = 1;
    $input = array('data' => json_encode($params));
    $options = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> true,  //return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER=> false,  //don't return headers
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER=> true,  //set referrer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=> 180,  //timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=> 180,  //timeout on response
        CURLOPT_POST=> 1,  //I am sending post data
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=> $input
    );

    $ch = curl_init("www.example.com");
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was working fine. But small changes on it. Replace `$input = array('data' => json_encode($params));` to `$input = http_build_query($params);`